# C# DateTime FormatException for dd MMM yyyy

Tags: c#

I am having a string "10-Dec-2013". I just want to convert it into Datetime type. The format should be "dd MMM yyyy".

I used the following code.

```
DateTime watchDate = DateTime.ParseExact("18-Nov-2013", "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

But i am getting FormatException. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Probably the most repeated question on SO

Answer (score 2):

You need the dashes:

```
DateTime watchDate = DateTime.ParseExact("18-Nov-2013", "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
//                                                         ^   ^
```

The format has to match your input.. which contains dashes.

If you want to re-store it in a string (not sure why you want to do that, since you already have the string you want) then you need to format it again:

```
string date = watchDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Comment: My output should be 18 Nov 2013 in the datetime object. Could you please share the code to get this output?

Comment: If i excute it, the output is 18-11-2013 00:00:00

Comment: Wait. Of course it will be 18-11-2013.. its a `DateTime` object.. not a string. If you want a string you need to format it again afterwards.

Comment: I don't even know how to answer that question. When you parse the date, the `DateTime` object will hold the exact date you wanted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41499/discussion-between-shafiq-abbas-and-simon-whitehead)

Comment: +1. @ShafiqAbbas please read following MSDN article first - [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) and than show sample of what you mean "If i excute it, the output is 18-11-2013 00:00:00 ".